# how to get [id] index from multiple indexes query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

below my sql query for example.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `box.id`
    from boxes as box 
    left join page_boxes as pbox 
         on box.id=pbox.bid 
         left join page_subcribers as pages 
             on pages.page_id=pbox.page_id 
             left join category_boxes as cbox 
                 on box.id=cbox.bid 
                 left join subcribers as catsb 
                     on cbox.category_id=catsb.cid 
     where pages.uid='".$session_id."' or catsb.uid='".$session_id."' 
     and box.status='".$approval."'")or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$total = $row['id'];
```

I need `box.id` as index `$total = $row['id'];` from this query but when i use this like `$total = $row['id'];` i am getting error

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\media\ctrx.php on line 12
```

how can i get this index id value ?

Comment: change `SELECT COUNT(*) as box.id` to `SELECT COUNT(*) as id`

Comment: You've aliased the count to `box.id`, so that's what you'll get in PHP, `$row['box.id']`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be `$total = $row['box.id'];`

Answer (score 0):

just remove backticks

```
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT   COUNT(*) as box.id
```

or you can use backticks like that

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT   COUNT(*) as `box`.`id`
```

but not table and column together with backticks

```
    `box.id`   // <---this wrong
```